# all element get: Sidenav Content w/ opacity

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to add a black background color to all page element when opened mobile nav on left screen.but my sidebar and content image don't get overlay and black background .My code :

```
 function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)";

 
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";

}
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide a sample of the html code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as expected. What you want cannot be achieved the way you tried to do it. What you want is an overlay. Just define a pseudo-element on your body tag and apply the background to the latter, that will work. You'll have to pay attention to the `z-value` though, to make sure that you navigation stays on top!

```js
$('#toggle-menu').on('click', function() {
  $('.overlay').toggleClass('show')
})
```

```css
.header,
.content,
.footer {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay:after{
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.overlay.show:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Page content
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    Footer
  </div>
  
  <button id="toggle-menu">Click me!</button>
</body>
```